# Export Nedb contents

Tags: node.js, nedb

I have an electron app that acts as a tool to speed up game development. When a user opens the app they can begin importing assets and setting custom properties. I store these properties in nedb. The way I have my application set up, every page change the properties from nedb are fetched and are immediately reflected on the page. I need to save these changes in a file the app can load and it would be intuitive to use nedb since it loads database info from a file optionally out of the box. However in the instance a user opens my app and begins working without a file, I have no way to store these changes for later use. I have found no docs for exporting the database on the fly.

Comment: So you're using nedb in memory and want to then save to a file?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: @tsturzl any ideas?

Comment: as far as I'm aware there is no way of doing this without reading through all the content of the previous DB and inserting it into a file backed DB. I'm curious to know why you don't just save it to a file to begin with. NeDB isn't really maintained any longer, lokiDB would be another solution. However its worth noting that they aren't intended to hold a lot of data, both loki and nedb will store all documents in memory and persist to disk.

Comment: @tsturzl That's what I figured. I'll have to peek into the module and see if I can't write an export function. As I mentioned in the post I'm using electron to make a native app. The user can open the app and begin editing files on the fly. This prevents me from saving to a file to begin with. I use NeDB to store small finger prints of data but it's enough to represent the entire app state making it ideal for an export feature.

Comment: Could you write to a randomly named temp file and then just move/rename that file when you decide where you want to save that file?

Comment: I could. Then I would always need to rename the file whenever the user saves for that current session. I have a couple ideas now. Thanks

Comment: One advantage to that approach is the possibility to save lost changes on crash.

Comment: I'm wondering about the same situation. I managed to get all the documents from the neDB storage. Although I'm having issues on saving it to a file... Any clue on this? thanks

Comment: @mluis you just export to a file

Comment: thanks @Maverick. I was using the saveAs method from 'file-saver'. The actual version on NPM didn't work but the one before that did the trick.

Comment: strange it didnt work. does your disk have the right permissions to write?